# Multiple sites in django with nginx and fcgi

Tags: python, django, nginx

I'm trying to serve multiple django projects using only one instance on fcgi with Nginx.

I saw that django's using the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE to handle the correct project but I can not tell him to choose a specific project at runtime.

I tried ./manage.py --settings=SETTINGS but it is only when you start the process and it can't be changed dynamically.

I also tried this on nginx:

```
location /foo {
  fastcgi_split_path_info   ^()(.*)$;
  fastcgi_param             DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE foo.settings;
  fastcgi_param             PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
  include                   fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_pass              127.0.0.1:8080;
}

location /bar {
  fastcgi_split_path_info   ^()(.*)$;
  fastcgi_param             DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE bar.settings;
  fastcgi_param             PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
  include                   fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_pass              127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

But when I print the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE, it is always at its default value.

So, anyone knows how to redirect a specific URL to a specific django project?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` cannot vary between requests. You'll have to run one fastcgi server per site. For example foo on `127.0.0.1:8080` and bar on `127.0.0.8081`.

Comment: Isn't it too greedy? It will run one django server per site.

Comment: Yes, running one server per site will probably require more RAM, but you might not have any choice. If your settings files are mostly the same, you may be able to run both sites from one project (for example, it is possible to set `urlconf` on a per-request basis using middleware). Without seeing the two settings file, we can't tell whether that is possible.

Comment: The sites must be similar. You must have the same INSTALLED_APS and many other things. Relative easy is to dynamically switch the SITE variable a template directory. Is it acceptable for you?

Comment: I finally used sockets because ports numbers are limited to 65536 (minus the 1024 not allowed to an unprivileged user) and I do not want to block others application to use them.

Answer (score 0):

theres a nice blog post i found as i wanted to figure out how to have multiple djnago projects on one server:

http://www.neuraladvance.com/2011/03/29/django-nginx-fastcgi-daemontools/